# How to Fix PowerShell Script from Basic Auth to Modern Auth

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-3.0

I have a PowerShell script that, after pinging a server address, uses Basic Auth to send an automated email via Task Scheduler. Microsoft has deprecated Basic Auth in Exchange Online in favor of Modern Auth, but I do not see clear directions for updating a PowerShell script to use Modern Auth.

This is an example of the Basic Auth that I need to convert.

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString “password” -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential (“user@place.com”, $secpasswd)
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer smtp.office365.com -Port 587 -From user@place.com -To otheruser@place.com -Subject test -Body test -Credential $mycreds -UseSsl"
```

Can someone point me to an example of Modern Auth being used in a similar script or share what I need to do to update and run the above script?

Many Thanks!

Comment: There are settings that must be in place first. Lots of docs exist on both topics.  ['PowerShell using modern auth'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+using+modern+auth%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: For example, as per the link above: [Connect to Exchange Online PowerShell using modern authentication with or without MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-scc-powershell?view=exchange-ps#connect-to-exchange-online-powershell-using-modern-authentication-with-or-without-mfa) and [Securely sending emails from PowerShell scripts with modern authentication enforced](https://tech.nicolonsky.ch/sending-emails-with-modern-auth/)

Comment: Thanks @postanote, what "settings must be in place first" are you referring to?

Comment: Also, fwiw, I am not an admin of anything Exchange or other. I don't have admin access to Azure, and my org wouldn't like it if I incurred a cost for something that was free just a short while ago. It seems like there should be a simple "This is the code to update your PS Send-Email Script from Basic to Modern", but the links provided are not so straight-forward and in some cases assume I have admin rights over Exchange or Azure and I don't.

Comment: There is no cost associated with authentication settings. One has been able to use Modern Auth for many years now, but many just choose to stick with basic authentication. As noted, that is not a thing. The auth types in AzureAD, M365, etc., have to be properly set up by an admin and imposed on target users. If users or other accounts are not properly set for target authentication needs, then it will not work. See my extended statement in the answer section, since it is too long for a regular comment. Refactoring code is not always 1:1 or simply straightforward, change is necesssary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @postanote for your suggestions, the fix eventually came down to this:

- from user@place.com I had to drop the 'place.com' and just keep the alias
- with -SmtpServer smtp.office365.com I had to drop 'office365.com' and replace with '[uni].edu'

Answer (score 1):

As per the resources in my original comment.

***Send-MailMessage is obsolete and no longer supported. Microsoft says this cmdlet does not guarantee a secure connection to SMTP servers. As per:***

- https://aka.ms/SendMailMessage

Therefore use the below:

- [Send-MgUserMail - MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.users.actions/send-mgusermail?view=graph-powershell-1.0)

***Note: Send-MgUserMail requires a more complex parameter structure.***

```
$EmailMessageContent=@'
<Strong> This is a Test Message</Strong><br>
Modern auth testing
'@

$params = @{
    Message = @{
        Subject = "Using MSGraph"
        Body = @{
            ContentType = "html"
            Content = $EmailMessageContent
        }
        ToRecipients = @(
            @{
                EmailAddress = @{
                    Address = "SomeRecipientEmaiAddress"
                }
            }
        )

    }
}
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes Mail.Read
Send-MgUserMail -UserId 'SomeSenderEmailAddress' -BodyParameter $params
```

Point of note:

SMTP AUTH will still be available when Basic authentication is permanently disabled on October 1, 2022. The reason SMTP will still be available is that many multi-function devices such as printers and scanners can't be updated to use modern authentication.

See also the below for full details of the why and so on... (and more sample code):

- [Authenticate an IMAP, POP or SMTP connection using OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth)
- [Moving on from Send-MailMessage: Sending Email from PowerShell using
  the Graph API](https://practical365.com/upgrade-powershell-scripts-sendmailmessage/#:%7E:text=The%20Send-MailMessage%20cmdlet%20depends%20on%20the%20SMTP%20AUTH,mean%20that%20an%20off-the-shelf%20replacement%20cmdlet%20is%20available)

> The Send-MailMessage Conundrum
>
> Largely because of history, Exchange Online supports a wide variety of
> connectivity protocols. Microsoft is making some progress to convince
> customers to disable basic authentication for protocols they never
> use, and has upgraded older protocols like POP3 and IMAP4 to use OAuth
> 2.0 for modern authentication. ***As discussed in this blog, tenants will need to find PowerShell scripts which call the Send-MailMessage cmdlet
> and eventually upgrade the code with a more modern method to send
> email.***
>
> The Send-MailMessage cmdlet depends on the SMTP AUTH protocol to send
> email using basic authentication. Microsoft announced OAuth 2.0
> support for SMTP AUTH in April 2020, but this doesn’t mean that an
> off-the-shelf replacement cmdlet is available. Microsoft says that the
> announcement “is for interactive applications to enable OAuth for IMAP
> and SMTP [AUTH].” In effect, this means mail clients or other
> applications which send, read, or otherwise process email. A quick
> trip to the referenced page leaves no doubt that this means more than
> replacing a few lines of code in a PowerShell script.