# How to send an email with powershell

Tags: powershell

How the heck do you send an email with powershell? I have the following code:

```
$Username = "test@yahoo.com"
$Password = "testpassword"
 
$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username, $SecurePassword
 
$RcptTo = "somebody@mailserver.com"
$Subject = "Yahoo Test"
$Body = "This is a test message"
Send-MailMessage -From $Username -To $RcptTo -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer smtp.mail.yahoo.com -Port 587 -UseSsl -Credential $Credentials
```

But am receiving the following error:

```
Send-MailMessage : Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the security for the connection. Add this to the top of your script.

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

[ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol?view=net-6.0)

***Point of note:***

> [Send-MailMessage is obsolete and no longer supported. Microsoft says
> this cmdlet does not guarantee a secure connection to SMTP
> servers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73692129/how-to-fix-powershell-script-from-basic-auth-to-modern-auth/73698320#73698320)